# Como criar uma hierarquia de select & option de categorias e subcategorias (MVC)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, mvc

Estou criando um sistema de select & option para um marketplace, onde ao selecionar uma categoria do primeiro select irá gerar um outro select com as opções de subcategoria da categoria selecionada.

Porém, para que eu não tenha que escrever valor por valor no script Java, queria utilizar o array que estou utilizando no código HTML.

Como posso fazer isso?

exemplo de como gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem os códigos que estou utilizando

**MODEL:**

```
    public function getCategory($data) {
        $sql = "SELECT name, oc_category.category_id, oc_category_path.level, oc_category.parent_id, oc_category_path.path_id
  FROM oc_category_description LEFT JOIN oc_category
    ON oc_category_description.category_id = oc_category.category_id
    LEFT JOIN oc_category_path ON oc_category_description.category_id = oc_category_path.category_id
    WHERE oc_category_description.language_id = 2";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

**VIEW:**

HTML

```
<select name="product-category" id='level0' size='10' class="form-control">
    <option value="teste0">--Select an Item--</option>

    <?php foreach($product_categories as $product_category){ ?>
        <?php if($product_category['parent_id'] == 300 && $product_category['level'] == 0){ ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $product_category['category_id'] ?>"><?php echo $product_category['name'] ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

</select>

<select name='product-subcategory' id="level1" size='10' class="form-control">

            <option value="">--Select an Item--</option>

        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Javascript

```js
<?php foreach($product_categories as $product_category){ ?>
 <?php if($product_category['parent_id'] == 59 && $product_category['level'] == 1){ ?>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#level0").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == "59") {  
            $("#level1").html("<option value="<?php $product_category['category_id']; ?>"><?php $product_category['name']; ?></option>
   ");
        } else if (val == "teste0") {
            $("#level1").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        } 
    });
});
 <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$data['product_categories'] = array();

    $category_info = $this->model_account_customerpartner->getCategory(); //$category_id

    foreach ($category_info as $category) {

        if ($category) {
            $data['product_categories'][] = array(
                'level'  => $category['level'],
                'name' => $category['name'],
                'parent_id' => $category['parent_id'],
                'path_id' => $category['path_id'],
                'category_id' => $category['category_id']
            );
        }
    }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Gostaria de resolver o quanto antes.

Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Comment: Tá errado ,amigo. Vc está fazendo um loop de código JS dentro do PHP. Tem reformular a lógica e o código.

Comment: Valeu. Se tiver alguma ideia de como posso reformular a lógica, avise!

Comment: Uma ideia eh ler os manuais dos metodos (jQuery) pra entender como funcionam.